# M4 Circuit Macros with TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX 2.9/Windows 7

Tags: texniccenter

I'm trying to run M4 Circuit Macros with TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX 2.9/Windows 7 but keep getting a compile error as follows:

```
pdflatex> I can't finde file 'quick'
pdflatex> l.6   \input quick
```

I presume this means that the *.m4 extension is not correctly linked to `m4.exe`.

The TeX file I'm using is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
    \input quick
\end{document}
```

And the `quick.m4` file (in the same directory) is:

```
.PS
cct_init
elen = 0.75
Origin: Here
source(up_ elen); llabel(-,v_s,+)
resistor(right_ elen); rlabel(,R,)
dot
{
    capacitor(down_ to (Here,Origin))
    rlabel(+,v,-); llabel(,C,)
    dot
}
line right_ elen*2/3
inductor(down_ Here.y-Origin.y); rlabel(,L,); b_current(i)
line to Origin
.PE
```

Following the info I've found (in particular http://staff.ee.sun.ac.za/pjrandewijk/wiki/index.php/M4_Circuit_Macros_-_Installation and http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=10133), I've done the following steps already:

1)  copy m4.exe, regex2.dll and dpic.exe to "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin"

2)  copy M4 Macros to "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\circuits_macros"

3)  add "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9" to user variable "M4PATH"

4)  Start -> All Programs -> MikTeX 2.9 -> Maintenance (Admin ) -> Settings (Admin)
    [General] Tab and click the [Refresh FNDB]

5)  associate *.m4 extension with TeXnicCenter

6)  set up an output profile in TeXnicCenter which selects M4 and dpic as post-processors and pass the (as far as I understand) correct arguments

Any pointers where I've missed a step? Thanks very much!

Comment: I don't have miktex to test, but shouldn't that be `\input quick.m4` ?

Comment: As far as I understand--no; and that's in line with the M4 docu (http://staff.ee.sun.ac.za/pjrandewijk/downloads/latex/circuit_macros/CMman.pdf, page 2). With the extension added, the processor tries to interpret the M4 file as TeX code, which obviously won't work.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `latex` with `pstricks` or loading something to support it with `pdflatex`?

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to run `latex` on it. The M4 stuff is supposed to go first, then that produces code which gets input into a LaTeX document. At least, so [this guide](http://www.iceamplifiers.co.uk/latex/circuitdiags/circuitdiags.pdf) suggests. I can't see how it can work otherwise: `\input` uses the `.tex` extension by default but, in any case, what you are inputting is meaningless to TeX. I think it has to be transformed *first*. Note that although the guide configures things as 'post-processors' it says that the LaTeX tab *does not include latex* so they are post-nothing.